# Best way to initialize class members?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using the c++11 standard, I can initialize class members in two ways:

```
class MyClass
{
private: 
    int a = 5;
};
```

or

```
class MyClass
{
private: 
    int a;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        a = 5;
    }
};
```

Is either method superior to the other for any reason, or is it more an individual style choice?

Comment: You're missing an example using ctor initializers. And the second example is simply assigning a value to `a` since it's already been initialized. Less important for integral types more important for complex ones.

Comment: @KaiSchmidt: CaptionObvious is referring to this: `MyClass() : a(5) {}`, and he meant you are "*assigning a value to `a` **after** it's already been initialized*".

Comment: I see. Should I want to use this method to initialize more than one member, what would the syntax look like?

Comment: `MyClass() : member1(value), member2(value), ... {}`

Comment: @Remy Feel free to write your own answer instead of hijacking mine...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I did not hijack it, I simply clarified it. You still get credit for it.

Comment: @Remy Yes I get credit for something I didn't write! And my name is alongside content I didn't write. I don't like that. Please don't add enough to fundamentally change an answer. Yes, we encourage edits here, but for corrections and whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example is *not* initialisation.

So, of the two examples, the first is the best way to initialise class members.

The traditional way to initialise looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private: 
    int a;
public:
    MyClass()
      : a(5)
    {}
};
```

Though we now have inline initialisers as in your first example, since C++11.

Comment: As per my second question, is it better to use ctor initializers or inline ones?

Comment: @KaiSchmidt: "Better" according to which metric? For whom? In what situation? You haven't stated any conditions, goals or criteria. Therefore, your question is impossible to answer. Stop looking for hard and fast rules.

Comment: Just use whatever is easier, they resolve to the same byte code.  ctor init lists can be used on very old compilers, but that's its only benefit and it's outweighed instantly if you prefer inlining even slightly

Answer (score 3):

[This page from the Standard C++ Foundation](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists) suggests that, all else being equal, you should prefer to use an initializer list. That is:

Prefer

```
class Foo {
  public:
     Foo(int bar) : m_bar(bar) { }
  private:
    int m_bar;
};
```

over

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int bar) {
      m_bar = bar;
    }
  private:
    int m_bar;
};
```

Their rationale:

> Consider the following constructor that initializes member object `x_`
>   using an initialization list: `Fred::Fred() : x_(whatever) { }`. The
>   most common benefit of doing this is improved performance. For
>   example, if the expression whatever is the same type as member
>   variable `x_`, the result of the whatever expression is constructed
>   directly inside `x_` — the compiler does not make a separate copy of the
>   object. Even if the types are not the same, the compiler is usually
>   able to do a better job with initialization lists than with
>   assignments.
>
> The other (inefficient) way to build constructors is via assignment,
>   such as: `Fred::Fred() { x_ = whatever; }`. In this case the expression
>   whatever causes a separate, temporary object to be created, and this
>   temporary object is passed into the `x_` object’s assignment operator.
>   Then that temporary object is destructed at the `;`. That’s inefficient.
>
> As if that wasn’t bad enough, there’s another source of inefficiency
>   when using assignment in a constructor: the member object will get
>   fully constructed by its default constructor, and this might, for
>   example, allocate some default amount of memory or open some default
>   file. All this work could be for naught if the whatever expression
>   and/or assignment operator causes the object to close that file and/or
>   release that memory (e.g., if the default constructor didn’t allocate
>   a large enough pool of memory or if it opened the wrong file).
>
> Conclusion: All other things being equal, your code will run faster if
>   you use initialization lists rather than assignment.

Regarding default initialization (such as `Foo(): m_bar(5) { }`) I would also go with the initializer list approach (or the C++11 member initialization approach) just for consistency with the above guideline.